# Can't get background image to appear in a div

Tags: html, css

I have this css with a converted SVG in it

```css
.thumbup-new { background:url("data:image/png;base64,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"); }
```

```html
<div class="thumbup-new"></div>
```

I see nothing, is my encoding wrong ?
I copied my svg image (which I got via a google search) to this online site  http://freeonlinetools24.com/base64-image
and then copied the result to my css

Comment: Have you tried setting the size of the div ?

Comment: You say svg but the data type is `image/png`................

Comment: I just used the online converter, it produced the css

Comment: @Rory - what answer did you accept?

Answer (score 1):

Give size to div first, if you give large enough size image will appear.

If div is smaller, then set background-size to get image in the div

```css
.thumbup-new {
  background: url("data:image/png;base64,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");
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: contain;

}
```

```html
<div class="thumbup-new"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the size of the image, and, of course, the `display:block`: see the [demo](http://jsbin.com/didowozuyo/edit?html,css,output).

```
 display: block;
 height: 520px;
 width: 520px;
```

You can add the `background-size: contain`, like this:

```
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
```

Comment: Default for a div is `display: block`, isn't necessary to add.

Comment: Uh, yes! But passing the display block you are sure that also applying it to an inline elment the CSS works

Comment: If it's an inline element you want this applied to, you would make it inline-block..

Comment: thanks, this worked as well as the answer I accepted